# Devise registration email not arriving "Delivered mail" is weird and contains Macbook name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, devise, ruby-on-rails-6

Please can someone help me. I have set up sendGrid with devise. I have followed numerous tutorials and done everything correct but after a user signs up the log file site with the following lines:

```
Rendering devise/mailer/confirmation_instructions.html.erb
Rendered devise/mailer/confirmation_instructions.html.erb (Duration: 0.4ms | Allocations: 91)
Devise::Mailer#confirmation_instructions: processed outbound mail in 3.7ms
```

After what seems like an eternity the actual page redirects on the front end and the log updates with the following. If you look at the first line "Delivered Mail" and the "Message ID" they contain some crazy random email address with my Macbook name.

```
Delivered mail 5e7293e497bf4_4b8a3ff2574a84c04004a@Gerards-MBP-2.mail (60180.2ms)
Date: Wed, 18 Mar 2020 21:34:28 +0000
From: hey@test.com
Reply-To: hey@test.com
To: gerardd1@googlemail.com
Message-ID: <5e7293e497bf4_4b8a3ff2574a84c04004a@Gerards-MBP-2.mail>
Subject: Confirmation instructions
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<p>Welcome gerardd1@googlemail.com!</p>

<p>You can confirm your account email through the link below:</p>

<p><a href="http://localhost:3000/users/confirmation?confirmation_token=bJiYjwaRVzvbDPc7F9Y4">Confirm my account</a></p>

Redirected to http://localhost:3000/verify
Completed 302 Found in 62111ms (ActiveRecord: 75.1ms | Allocations: 33693)
```

**Config Settings:**

**devise.rb**

```
config.mailer_sender = 'hey@test.com'
```

**environment.rb**

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :user_name => ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'],
  :password => ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'],
  :domain => 'heroku.com',
  :address => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
  :port => 465,
  :authentication => :plain,
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

**development.rb**

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost', port: 3000 }
```

If anyone could help me with this I would be so grateful. It has cost me a day and a half so far.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Please put up your config files.

Comment: thanks 

devise.rb

Comment: I need to see what is inside your config... or have you already solved the problem?

Comment: Hey @BeulahAkindele I have just updated what I added to the config files above. Do you want me to copy and paste the full files? Also, if I have missed any files just let me know. Thanks for looking into this for me.

Comment: And you've set up your `.env` file to have your SendGrid username and password?

Comment: Yes, I even took out the ENV variables and added the username and password directly in the file and it still had the same issue.

Comment: So the issue now is that emails aren't getting delivered to the email you specified? Having the random string and your computer name printed out seems normal to me... my mailers always do that. I believe it is for logging purposes as those logs are only visible to you, even when running on production from a host like Heroku.

Comment: ahh, ok! Yes the email is not being delivered. After I signup the log seems like its just hanging there for ages and then it Delivered Mail etc...

Comment: My sendGrid dashboard has no activity logged in it so it seems like its not getting that far.   Do I need to add anything else to the Environment files maybe?

Answer (score 0):

How about you try this in your `development.rb`:

```
  config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false

  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: "localhost" }
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    domain: 'localhost',
    address: "stmp.sendgrid.net",
    port: 3000,
    authentication: :plain,
    enable_starttls_auto: true,
    user_name: ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'],
    password: ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD']
}
```

Also, if you can... try to run it from production. In my -little- experience, it is always easier to get mailers working on a production service like Heroku than in development from a PC.

Also, make sure to not upload your SendGrid credentials online anywhere, like GitHub. It is a security risk and will have your account disabled. Make sure your `.env` file is in your `.gitignore` and you remove the credentials from your `environment.rb`.

Comment: So I got it working. 
Your code above helped me to solve it. Thank you so much. 
I removed the port number in my environments.rb file and let the line in the development.rb stipulate the port. I was refering to port 465 in the main file and 300 in the dev version. 

Once I changed that it worked. I would not have got it without your help!!! Thank you so much for sticking with me.

Comment: You are ever so welcome. Accept the answer so the question will be closed and people with similar problems will be able to reference it. @Gerard

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I was stipulating the PORT in both the environment.rb and development.rb files. Once I removed it from environment.rb it worked.